# Проблема парсинга информации python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, requests, bs4

Пытаюсь парсить данную информацию, которая подгружается разрешением гугла

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мой код :

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def  main():

    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_extension(
        r'C:/Users/Пользователь/Desktop/ПРОГРАММИРОВАНИЕ/Steam Inventory Helper - Интернет-магазин Chrome.crx')

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options,executable_path=r'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chromedriver.exe')

    driver.get = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29'

    r = requests.get(driver)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    data = [div for div in soup.find('div', {'class': 'sticker-image'})]

    result = []

    for i in range(len(data)):
        try:
            result.append(data[i]['title'])
        except TypeError:
            continue

    print(result)
```

Прошу помочь, данный код не выдает не какой информации...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И какие есть еще способы чтобы вывести данные из title (со скрина выше)

Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `find_elements_by_class_name` для поиска по названию класса или `find_elements_by_id` для поиска по id. Оба возвращают массив из найденных элементов.

Для меня работает следующий код:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29'

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary="/usr/bin/firefox-esr")
driver.get(url)

for element in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('descriptor'):
    print(element.text)

driver.quit()
```